# How to retrieve data from a webpage to be displayed in app

Tags: java, android

I have a website and I want to retrieve some data from the website and display in my android app. What is the best way and any sample on how to accomplish it?

Should I use JSON file and retrieve in my app?

What if there are certain texts that are displayed on my webpage that I also want to display in my app? So every time those texts changes the app displays the updated texts.

Comment: Which website is it? Does it offer an API of some sort?

Comment: Its just my website... WWW.pagesbyz.com. I don't think so, no API.

Comment: Use HTML scraping. The answer by @user3053234 might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsoup.org/ It's all I have to say :) hope that helps

Comment: That might work... Wow!!! After looking it seems like I can extract any web page, security threat?

Comment: Not a threat since it only parses data that is publicly available.

Comment: Ohhhhh... Of course. I realized that afterward. Thanks for the clarification :)